# How to compute limit $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( \frac{n-1}{n+2} \right)^{n+2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( \frac{n-1}{n+2} \right)^{n+2}$$

I do not have any ideas. Need some tips.

Comment: You'll probably want to use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x$.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint 1: $$\frac{n-1}{n+2} = 1 - \frac{3}{n+2}$$

Hint 2: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e.$$

Solution:

> Taking $x=-\frac{n+2}{3}$ gives $$\left(1 - \frac{3}{n+2}\right)^{n+2} = \left(1 - \frac{3}{n+2}\right)^{-\frac{n+2}{3} \cdot (-3)} \to e^{-3} .$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [long division](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=divide%20(n-1)%2F(n%2B2)), you can transform

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( \frac{n-1}{n+2} \right)^{n+2}$$

to

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( 1+ \frac{-3}{n+2} \right)^{n+2}$$

You can use the change of variables $n+2=k$

$$\lim_{k \to +\infty} \left( 1+ \frac{-3}{k} \right)^{k}$$

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function),  we have $$e^x = \lim_{k \to +\infty} \left( 1+ \frac{x}{k} \right)^{k}$$

Therefore our limit is $e^{-3}$

P.S. We can derive $e^x$ from just knowing $e = \lim_{k \to +\infty} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{k} \right)^{k}$

Answer (score 1):

Call the limit $L$. Note that
\begin{align*}
\log(L)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+2)\log\left(
\frac{n-1}{n+2}
\right) \\
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(
\frac{n-1}{n+2}
\right)}{\frac{1}{n+2}} \\
&\overset{L}{=}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{3}{(n+2)(n-1)}}{-\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}} \\
&=
-3\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+2)(n-1)} \\
&=-3
\end{align*}
where the equality marked $L$ uses L'Hopital's rule. Hence $L=e^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+2-3}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{-3}{n+2}\right)^{n+2}$$
do the change of variable $u=n+2$, we have $n\to\infty =>u\to\infty$
then we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{-3}{u}\right)^{u}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{u}{-3}}\right)^{u}$$
again other change of variable, this is $w=-\frac{u}{3}=>-3w=u$, when $u\to\infty$ then $w\to \infty$
finally the limit is:
$$\lim_{w\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)^{-3w}=\left[\lim_{w\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)^{w}\right]^{-3}=e^{-3}$$

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up like this... Call the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} ((n-1)/(n+2))^{n+2} =L$ . Then take the natural log of both sides of the equation so you get $\ln(L)= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (n+2)\ln((n-1)/(n+2))$ (because of log rules). Then you can say this is equivalent to $\ln(L)= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} ln((n-1)/(n+2))/(n+2)^{-1}$ Then you can do l'Hospital's rule because you now have an indeterminant form. This yields $-3$. Remember that $-3$ is $\ln(L)$ so just have $e$ raised to both sides to yield limit $L = e^{-3}$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\ln(n-1)/(n+2))/(n+2)^{-1}$, i.e., with a $\ln$ rather than what you've written?

Comment: yeah thanks! lot to keep track of! i fixed it